# Maven looking for Jersey dependency when using javax (Invocation Interface)

Tags: java, maven, jersey, client, jax-rs

I am trying to create a simple client that can send get request to a given url.
I am trying to use javax tools but encounter weird behavior that I couldn't find answer anywhere for..

My code looks like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public static Response processRequest(String url, String method) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(); // (Http.java:44)
        WebTarget target = client.target(url);
        Builder builder = target.request();
        builder.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Invocation Invo = builder.buildGet(); 
        Response res = Invo.invoke();

        return res;
    }
```

As you can see I am using `javax.ws.rs.core` library and all relevent dependencies are in pom.xml

The weird issue here is that when I execute code, it is failing with the following error -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
        at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:110)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:121)
        at scr.cps.utils.Http.processRequest(Http.java:44)
        at scr.cps.utils.Http.doGet(Http.java:69)
        at scr.cps.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:111)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:209)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:94)
```

Can someone help me understand why maven i looking for `org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder` when I clearly import from `import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;`.. I am not using jersey anywhere in my code

Answer (score 0):

ClientBuilder is using jersey's JerseyClientBuilder class as default (apparently you must use a class that is a sub class of ClientBuilder) and therefore was looking for it. 
I chose to use ResteasyClient for executing my requests.

I added the dependency -

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And validated the jar was added to my repository
and it works! :)